# Arc Theme on Ubuntu 16.04 looks weird

Tags: unity, nautilus, themes, 16.04

I just installed **Arc theme** on Ubuntu 16.04 using version for ubuntu 15.10 (that's what's available on creator's website: http://software.opensuse.org/download.html?project=home%3AHorst3180&package=arc-theme)

Here's how it looks on my setup:

[image: Arc theme issue]

I activated this theme using Unity Tweak Tool.

Firstly in Nautilus the left panel looks weird - it should also be transparent.
Secondly every window gets a little thicker just below titlebar on both sides.

Do you know if there's a way to fix it? I really like this theme, probably best available.

Comment: Are you installed gtk2-engines-murrine?

Comment: Same happens to me and i have murrine engine installed.

Comment: I only installed arc theme, ubuntu-restricted-extras and unity tweak tool. Nothing more

Answer (score 4):

Hello follow the guide manual guide in https://github.com/horst3180/arc-theme
I was having the same problem but its solved now.

Comment: So I followed Manual Installation guide as you suggested and now Nautilus looks as it should. But still I have these problems:
- windows get thicker just under titlebars (shown on screenshot in the first post)
- there is no transparency

Comment: Same issue for me.

Comment: @Loreno Transparency feature won't work with Unity, it is for Gnome shell.

Answer (score 3):

#### Run following Commands,

`sudo apt install git gnome-themes-standard gtk2-engines-murrine gtk2-engines-pixbuf`

`mkdir ~/.themes; cd ~/.themes/ && rm -rf Arc*`

`git clone https://github.com/sagarpanchal/arc-theme-ubuntu.git`

`cp -r arc-theme-ubuntu/Arc* . && rm -rf arc-theme-ubuntu`

`gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme 'Arc-Darker'`

#### After running above commands, open unity tweaks and change your theme!

Comment: If you do this, you may have to remove Arc folders from /usr/share/themes (or `apt-get uninstall arc-theme` if you installed it with apt)

Comment: @unhammer Not necessary. Themes in ~/.themes will override themes in /usr/share/themes.

Answer (score -1):

I've had the same issue, however you can fix it by doing the following

```
cd /usr/share/themes
sudo chown -R $USER themes
```

This may not work for you however this has fixed the same issue you are having on my setup

**Running On Ubuntu 16.04 LTS**

Answer (score -2):

O.k., after downloading using the command:

```
git clone https://github.com/sagarpanchal/arc-theme-ubuntu.git
```

In my home directory I started Nautilus as `sudo` and copied the 3 folders inside `arc-theme-ubuntu` named `arc`, `arc-dark` and `arc-darker` and changed to the `/usr/share/themes` directory and pasted them there. Then started the tweak tool and changed to arc and now it looks right.